# Easy save or update of hierarchical object gorm

Tags: grails, grails-orm

How can I easily deal with nested properties in GORM?

If I have a map of properties including nested properties:

```
def mymap = [
   id : '1',
   name : 'first name',
   subs : [[
      subid : 1,
      name : 'first sub name'
   ],[
      subid : 2,
      name : 'second sub name'
   ]]
]
```

And I have the following domain objects:

```
class Node {
  int id
  String name
  static hasMany = [subs:Sub]
}
class Sub {
  int id
  String name
}
```

If I create a new node with the map

```
new Node(myMap).save()
```

It complains with something like >> Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'java.util.Set' for property 'subs'

Same goes for updates when I try with

```
node.properties = myMap
node.save()
```

Is there no way I can do this automatically but have to traverse it manually?

Comment: Data binding doesn't take nested objects.

Answer (score 1):

Your map contents look more or less like some JSON.

My first try (if it were failing out of the box) would be to try to use JSON converters and if that still fails, I would probably hook my JSON marshaller for the Node type.

Answer (score 0):

```
def mymap = [
   id : '1',
   name : 'first name',
   subs : [[
      subid : 1,
      name : 'first sub name'
   ],[
      subid : 2,
      name : 'second sub name'
   ]] as Set
]
```

Comment: Did solve the set problem, yes, but it originated apparently from the child map. Can't add complex types to the map, so now having: default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.LinkedHashSet' to required type 'java.util.Set' for property 'subs'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.util.LinkedHashMap] to required type [Sub for property 'subs[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]